# Does OpenIddict violates OAuth and OpenId Connect specifications?

Tags: oauth, openid-connect, openiddict

I could not find any information in the documentation of OpenIddict regarding this.

Let's look at one of the official OpenIddict [samples](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/blob/dev/samples/Velusia/Velusia.Server/Controllers/AuthorizationController.cs#L130).

```
// If the consent is implicit or if an authorization was found,
// return an authorization response without displaying the consent form.
case ConsentTypes.Implicit:
case ConsentTypes.External when authorizations.Any():
case ConsentTypes.Explicit when authorizations.Any() && !request.HasPrompt(Prompts.Consent):

// Create the claims-based identity that will be used by OpenIddict to generate tokens.
...
```

From that code I can say:

1. Authorization Server allows to configure clients in the way that they DO NOT require consent from Resource Owner (ConsentTypes.Implicit)
2. Authorization Server allows somebody else to decide Resource Owner's consent.

Having that in mind - let's take a look at OpenId Connect specification about [consent](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#Consent).

"*Once the End-User is authenticated, the Authorization Server **MUST obtain** an authorization decision before releasing information to the Relying Party. When permitted by the request parameters used, this MAY be done through an interactive dialogue with the End-User that makes it clear what is being consented*"

And OAuth [specification (RFC)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1)

"*(B)  The authorization server authenticates the resource owner (via the user-agent) and establishes **whether the resource owner grants or denies** the client's access request.*"

Another example again from [Open Id Connect documentation](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#CodeFlowSteps)

"*4. Authorization Server **obtains End-User Consent/Authorization***"

The question:

Is this a violation of OAuth + OpenId Connect protocol? It seems that not asking Resource Owner's consent is a security violation when Client can easily get access to protected resources. The same happens in `External` consent type. How some other admin could decide Resource Owner's consent?

OR is it the responsibility of registering clients to NOT allow them to use implicit/external consent types?

Answer (score 1):

The original OAuth specs from 2012 supported 4 main parties:

- Resource owner (user)
- Client (application)
- Resource server (API)
- Authorization server

The most general flow involves third party applications accessing the user's personal resources, therefore requiring consent. OAuth is also a general security framework though, rather than a fixed solution.

In a majority of application use cases, the assets don't belong to the user. Eg they belong to your company or a vendor who is selling you something. In those cases, consent is disabled, which is why OpenIddict allows it to be disabled. All authorization servers support this, to avoid prompting the user in unnatural ways.

When personal assets are involved, the MUST use consent remains important, as you indicate. Ultimately though, OAuth is all about protecting data  The behaviours you choose when applying it will depend on your business use case.

**EXAMPLES**

- A doctor logs on to a health system to view patient records. He does not consent to allow the system to use medical data. Those assets are the responsibility of the health system.

- You log into Netflix. You are using Netflix's TV and film assets, so you are not asked to consent.
- When you register with Netflix, or do something that needs payment (your resources), you are asked to consent.
- When I sign into GitHub I do not consent. They store my code permanently so a consent prompt would not change that.
- If I grant codacy (a third party service) access to my GitHub code, I am asked to consent to give it read privileges.

**TOKEN PRIVILEGES**

The client does not have rights to do whatever it wants with tokens. Tokens should be issued to clients with least privilege, and locked down using scopes and claims. Tokens and consent behaviour are designed by the party that stores the data.

Comment: Sorry, could you provide any examples of `In a majority of application use cases, the assets don't belong to the user? In those cases, consent is disabled.`
What comes to my mind is: any data related to Resource Owner that Client would like to have access to should be consented to by Resource Owner.

Comment: Even more, since the token will represent Resource Owner rights and the Client will have the right to do WHATEVER it wants with this token - for me, it seems that it should be always the case to get consent from Resource Owner.

Comment: Added some examples above - as I be say, whether an OAuth secured solution prompts for consent is up to the designer.

Comment: thank you very much for those examples. Regarding token privileges - I agree, I meant the client can do whatever is allowed by scopes in token.

Comment: Regarding the examples, it seems like you mean sign in when I mean authorize, let me explain: Sign into {GIthub, Netflix, Google, etc) is not oauth flow, you could investigate the network tool in browser. In case of Github - when you see YOUR repos no Authorization token, only cookies. There is nothing related to OAuth in all cases,  even "authorize" endpoint is not called. That's why no consent. As far as I know OAuth is about third-party access. {Grant codacy, register WITH Netflix somewhere else} are the OAuth use cases that's why consent. And my question was about OAuth, not sign in.

Comment: OAuth is used in many non-third-party use cases though, due to the way it externalizes difficult security. Apps and APIs then need only much simpler code. They no longer implement lower level security, such as authentication in many ways, and API message credentials. So there are architectural benefits, even when no third party apps are involved. That is why consent is optional in your authorization server.

Comment: Isn't it a inproper usage of this protocol/specification (OAuth+ OpenIdConnect). As stated in RFC (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)

"The OAuth 2.0 authorization framework enables a third-party
   application to obtain limited access to an HTTP service ... .... .... on
   behalf of a resource owner by orchestrating an approval interaction
   between the resource owner and the HTTP service"